# How to get selected date when dynamic DateTimepicker change on xamarin form?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I working on a app that needs dynamic fields for filling form.
this form may contains multiple timesheets and each timesheet include startDate and finishDate.
so how can set property_change on datepicker that creates on runtime?

```
if (field.Type == "Timesheets"){
DatePicker sDate = new DatePicker();
 sDate.StyleId = field.Name;
  sDate.PropertyChanged += sDate_changed;

DatePicker fDate = new DatePicker();
 fDate.StyleId = field.Name;
  sDate.PropertyChanged += fDate_changed;
}



  private async void sDate_changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

           // here I don't have access to sdate and fdate

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your code, I recommend you to add event `DateSelected`  for your DatePicker.

replace code:

```
   sDate.PropertyChanged += sDate_changed;
   fDate.PropertyChanged += fDate_changed;
```

with:

```
   sDate.DateSelected += SDate_DateSelected; 
   fDate.DateSelected += FDate_DateSelected;
```

> // here I don't have access to sdate and fdate

There are two ways to access `sdate` and `fdate`.

**Method 1**(just as Jason posted):

```
 async void  SDate_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                var picker = (DatePicker)sender;
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "selected date is: " + picker.Date, "OK");

            }
```

**Method 2**:

Since you have defined new variables for two `DatePicker`(`sdate` and `fdate`) , you can use the two variables(`sdate` and `fdate`) to access the selected date.

Please refer to the following code:

```
        sDate.DateSelected += SDate_DateSelected; 
        fDate.DateSelected += FDate_DateSelected;

        //method 2
        void Recalculate()
        {
            TimeSpan timeSpan = fDate.Date - sDate.Date;

            mLabel.Text = String.Format("{0} day{1} between dates",
                                                timeSpan.Days, timeSpan.Days == 1 ? "" : "s");
        }

         async void  SDate_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = (DatePicker)sender;
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "SDate_DateSelected : " + picker.Date, "OK");

            //Recalculate();
        }

        async void FDate_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = (DatePicker)sender;
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", " FDate_DateSelected : " + picker.Date, "OK");

            //Recalculate();
        }
```

**Note:**

I find that your code variable is being used incorrectly,please replace the following code:

```
DatePicker fDate = new DatePicker();
fDate.StyleId = field.Name;
sDate.PropertyChanged += fDate_changed;
```

with

```
DatePicker fDate = new DatePicker();
fDate.StyleId = field.Name;

// here it should be fDate not sDate
fDate.PropertyChanged += fDate_changed;
```

Answer (score 0):

that is what the `sender` parameter does

```
private async void sDate_changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (DatePicker)sender;

        // now you can access all the properties of the picker
    }
```

Comment: becase it's not on view yet, it gives error that (DatePicker)sender doesn't exist

Comment: then add a null check